# Declaring the type of collection in Java

Tags: java

What would be the difference between these two lines effectively?

```
ArrayList <MyClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
ArrayList <MyClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

Comment: Which version of java, it makes difference based on version.

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList <MyClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This one is valid in Java7.

---

```
ArrayList <MyClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

This one is valid in Java7, Java6 and Java5.